# zero amputation interpretation as dropout

Tags: neural-networks, dropout

Assume I'm trying to train a neural net on training data with some missing features across the training samples. Assume that I replace the missing feature with **zero**. Is this equal to the usage of dropout layer after the input layer ? (To simplify the math, let's also assume that I know the probability that a feature is missing - p. Is it equal to dropout(p)?)

Furthermore, I know that placing zero instead of the missing feature isn't that good idea because intuitively the network cannot distinguish between a missing feature and non missing feature with zero value. So what about if I set the value to zero but also freeze the weights that come out of the input neuron that represent the missing feature ? Is that a more reasonable approach ?

And to wrap up my questions - If both of my assumptions are true, why is using the Dropout at the input layer a bad idea while doing it at the hidden layers is okay ? Isn't the same indistinguishability is produced ? And isn't a good idea to freeze the weights of the hidden neurons which we drop during the dropout ?

Thank you,